# Is there a UIDocument equivalent for NSDocument.performSynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock()?

Tags: ios, nsdocument, uidocument

`UIDocument` only provides an asynchronous way of accessing file data:

- `performAsynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock()`

`NSDocument` provides an async AND synchronous version:

- `performAsynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock()`
- `performSynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock()`

In my iOS app, I now happen to need a **synchronous** version for my UIDocument. Is there a way to access the "background file access queue" of UIDocument another way so that I can schedule my synchronous block there?

Background:

My UIDocument is backed by a ZIP file. Reading is done directly from the ZIP file. On the first write operation, the ZIP file is extracted to a temporary directory. Extracting the ZIP needs to be done on the file access queue to prevent race conditions.

Same goes for accessing the data. Should the ZIP file happen to be unzipped right now (e.g. during autosave), any read operation has to wait for that to finish.